# Crop out ggplot2 whitespace around plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, whitespace, margin, crop

Is there a way to remove the white space surrounding a ggplot2 plot when the shape has been changed using `coord_fixed()`? I would like the white space above and below to be cropped away so that only the plotting area and axis labels remain. I am rendering the plot output in an R markdown file without saving.

```
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
 p + coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

The code below produces the following plot:

[image: plot with white space]

Comment: do you want something like this? `p + coord_equal() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  ggsave('plot.jpg', width = 6, height = 1.5, dpi = 300)
```

You get a plot with less white space:

[image]

Another option could be to use the png or jpeg device:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)

jpeg('plot.jpg', width = 600, height = 150)
p
dev.off()
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. Is this still working on your computer?

Comment: is this about rmarkdown or creating a image output? This seems like a hack if it works?

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a solution which also works in R markdown (i.e. output as PDF/HTML), this solved it for me: first set the aspect ratio and then remove the additional margin on the top via the `theme()` settings.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, shape = Species, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1/2) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(-0.30,0,0,0), "null")) # remove margin around plot
```

[image]

See also [this blog post](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/#changing-the-plot-margin) for more details.

Session info:
MacOs 10.13.6, R 3.6.3, ggplot2_3.3.1

Comment: may also be necessary to set the crop options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059235/7941188