# Adjusting figure margins in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pie-chart, figure

I am trying to adjust the piechart figure in my Rmarkdown document so that it spans the width of the page or at least becomes wide enough to fit all of the labels.

I have tried everything - adjusting `figure.height` and `figure.width`, margins with `par(mar)` and `par(oma)`, but nothing seems to work.  Either the pies themselves become smaller, or the labels are even more cut off. I would like the pies to be as large as possible with clearly visible labels, but every time it renders small pies and tiny labels.

Is there a workaround at least so that labels are not cut off (or can overlap the adjacent chart)? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

````
```{r, figure.align = "center", figure.height = 10, figure.width = 12}

par(mfrow=c(1,3), cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5) 
par(mar = c(4,2,4,2))
par(oma = c(3, 3, 3, 3))
pie(a, labels = lbls,  font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"), cex=2)
pie(b, lbls2, font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"), cex=2) 
mtext(side=3, text="Plan Breakdown: Top 20% of Users")
pie(c, lbls3,  font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"))
````

[image]

Comment: Can you give the entirety of the Rmd that you're using? which output format are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using the chunk option 'out.width'. Here is the Rmd file that I used. I think that it does what you want.

````
    ---
    output: pdf_document
    ---


    ```{r, out.width='\\textwidth', fig.height = 8, fig.align='center'}
    pie(c(0.57, 0.43), font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"))

    pie(c(0.57, 0.43), font = 2, col = c("blue", "orange"))
    ```
````

Comment: this changes nothing in my case

Answer (score 6):

Your figure size is constrained by the document margins unless you specify an out.width. If your figure width is larger than the margins of the page, then R Markdown/knitr will create a figure of the specified aspect ratio but shrink it down to fit within the margins.

To solve this, use out.width to set the width and height of the plot in the pdf. Something like:

`````
```{r, fig.align = "center", fig.height = 8, fig.width = 8,
    out.width = "8.5in"}

pie(a, labels = lbls,  font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"), cex=2)
pie(b, lbls2, font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"), cex=2) 
mtext(side=3, text="Plan Breakdown: Top 20% of Users")
pie(c, lbls3,  font = 2, col = c("tomato", "white"))
````
`````

See [this page on knitr chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, seems some cropping is applyied by default, adding this in the yaml-header worked for me:

```
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    fig_crop: no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to
File<Preferences<Editor then
scroll to:
"Maximum width of text editor"
set that to
"1200px"

this would increase the width of the Markdown document