# Reduce white space between ggplot and caption in an Rmd PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, r-markdown

I have the following two plots in an RMD PDF using `ggarrange`. They're fine, but I'm a bit annoyed at the big white space between the caption and the actual plot. Is there any way I can reduce this space?

````
---
title: Report
author: My Name
date: "`r format(Sys.Date() - 30, '%B %Y')`"
params:
  logo: logo.jpg
  cover: cover.png
  iblue: 6d1d26
  igray: ffffff
documentclass: article
classoption: 
  - twocolumn
fontsize: 15
papersize: a4paper
output: 
  IReports::businessReport:
    keep_tex: TRUE
    latex_engine: xelatex
    resetStyleFiles: FALSE
header-includes: 
  - \newcommand{\logo}{`r gsub("_", "\\_", params$logo)`}
  - \newcommand{\cover}{`r gsub("_", "\\_", params$cover)`}
  - \newcommand{\iblue}{`r params$iblue`}
  - \newcommand{\igray}{`r params$igray`}
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
  - \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
include-before:
  - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents Page}
  - \renewcommand{\pagename}{Page}
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
# packages
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

# settings
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```


```{r fig6, fig.align='center', fig.cap="Currency (left) and Asset (Right) Allocation \\label{Figure6}", fig.width=5,fig.height=3, fig.pos='!h'}

library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

# Dataframes

currency_breakdown <- structure(list(Currency = structure(1:4, .Label = c("ZAR", "USD", 
"EUR", "Other"), class = "factor"), `Percent (%)` = c(52.25, 
41.87, 3.11, 2.77), Key = c("ZAR [52.25%]", "USD [41.87%]", "EUR [3.11%]", 
"Other [2.77%]")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

asset_breakdown <- structure(list(Asset = structure(c(4L, 3L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("Cash", 
"Money Market Securities", "Treasuries", "Agencies & Supras"), class = "factor"), 
    `Percent (%)` = c(1.02, 34.61, 33.06, 31.31), Key = c("Agencies & Supras [1.02%]", 
    "Treasuries [34.61%]", "Money Market [33.06%]", "Cash [31.31%]"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Plots

currency_breakdown_plot <- ggplot(currency_breakdown, aes("", `Percent (%)`, fill = Key)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white", size = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#063A5B','#bbacaf','#c7af76','#7c3042')) +
  labs(colour = NULL) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = c(.5,0),legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=7)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, override.aes = list(size = 1)))

asset_breakdown_plot <- ggplot(asset_breakdown, aes("", `Percent (%)`, fill = Key)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white", size = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#063A5B','#bbacaf','#c7af76','#7c3042'),
                    labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 20)) +
  labs(colour = NULL) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = c(.5,0),legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=7)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2,override.aes = list(size = 1)))

# ggarrange

ggarrange(currency_breakdown_plot, asset_breakdown_plot, nrow = 1)

```
````

[image]

Comment: Could you reformat the code as an rmarkdown document, also giving the YAML header and chunk options? We need to have this information to check that the expected outcome is correct.

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, I've edited it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `theme` option in `ggplot`. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528639/13249862), you could add this to your code: `plot.margin=unit(c(-0.20,0,0,0), "null")`.

Changing your code:

```
asset_breakdown_plot <- ggplot(asset_breakdown, aes("", `Percent (%)`, fill = Key)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white", size = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#063A5B','#bbacaf','#c7af76','#7c3042'),
                    labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 20)) +
  labs(colour = NULL) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = c(.5,0),legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=7), plot.margin=unit(c(-0.20,0,0,0), "null")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2,override.aes = list(size = 1)))

# ggarrange

ggarrange(currency_breakdown_plot, asset_breakdown_plot, nrow = 1)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks @bttomio