Using coord.fixed() in facetted ggplot creates white space above and below the plot in Rmarkdown (html, Pdf and doc)
Here is a short reprex
valN <- 2000
valCorr <- .7
matCov <- matrix(c(1, valCorr, valCorr, 1), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
vecMeans <- c(0, 0)
MASS::mvrnorm(n = valN, mu = vecMeans, Sigma = matCov) %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>%
  rename(Pre = `...1`,
         Post = `...2`) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number(),
         group = ID %% 2) -> tibDat

First a simple plot: no unnecessary white space.
ggplot(data = tibDat,
       aes(x = Pre, y = Post)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .1) +
  geom_smooth() +
  xlim(c(-4, 4)) +
  ylim(c(-4, 4)) +
  coord_fixed()

Now facet the plot without coord_fixed(), no unwanted white space.
ggplot(data = tibDat,
       aes(x = Pre, y = Post)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group),
             space = "free",
             ) +
  geom_point(alpha = .1) +
  geom_smooth() +
  xlim(c(-4, 4)) +
  ylim(c(-4, 4)) 

And then this which adds facetting and illustrates the additional white space appearing when I add coord_fixed().
ggplot(data = tibDat,
       aes(x = Pre, y = Post)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group),
             space = "free",
             ) +
  geom_point(alpha = .1) +
  geom_smooth() +
  xlim(c(-4, 4)) +
  ylim(c(-4, 4)) +
  coord_fixed()

The issue is there exporting to html, pdf or word.  Bigger reprex at https://www.psyctc.org/R/reprex_20240710.Rmd with and here in my Rblog.  TIA for any suggestions.

Well, this is a known issue when using coord_fixed but is not a bug in ggplot2. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328965/crop-out-ggplot2-whitespace-around-plot. The issue is that with coord_fixed the size of the exported plot will not adjust to both the width and height of the plotting device. As you are using Rmarkdown you might consider using knitr::plot_crop to get rid of the white space as suggested in this answer.

This is just a natural consequence of using coord_fixed, don't think it has anything to do with facets?

Thanks stefan.  That is a solution and I have updated my post in my Rblog expanding that. However, I don't agree with you or axeman that this is transparent behaviour.  It is a consequence of using facetting and I think the underlying grammar of graphics might expect coord_fixed to fix the aspect ratio of the facets not the entire plot or for it to have an option to clarify whether it is to be applied to facets if they exist.  However, thanks: I have a solution!

Nop. This is not related to using facets. The issue is only more apparent when using facets. And you will encounter a similar issue when using coord_polar or coord_sf, e.g. check the default example from ?geom_sf.
